# How do I keep NumPy array format after using np.delete?

Tags: arrays, numpy

I wanted to find a way to remove values outside my standard deviation and I think this nested loop format could work. The issue is I still want the array to remain an array, but when I delete a value that's outside the standard deviations and store it I think it turns my data into a 1 dimensional vector and doesn't preserve the original format. I am using NumPy. I would also be open to replacing inappropriate values with NaN although I'm not sure how to do that while also preserving the array format. Any help is appreciated!

In this case, da is an array and dc is another array (attempted) I am trying to paste the filtered data into.

```
for i in column_length_list:
    mean = np.mean(da[:,i]) 
    stdev = np.std(da[:, i]) 
    for j in da[:, i]: 
       if j > (2*stdev+mean) or j < (mean-2*stdev): 
          dc = np.array(np.delete(da, np.where(da == j)))
```

Comment: `np.delete` returns an array.  No need to wrap it any more.  Also try to use just one `delete` for the whole array, and for all rows or columnsvyou need to remove.  Don't do it in a loop.

Comment: Did you read, or reread `np.delete` docs after thses problems?  Quote: "If `axis` is None, `obj` is applied to the flattened array."

Comment: I got the axis and flattening issue fixed, it helps to set axis=0 as the function flattens by 1 dimension. I am still having an issue though where it doesn't appear the delete function deletes values from the previous conditional. I also removed the array function, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: In the above code you delete from the original `da` each time.  You don't save or reuse the `dc` from iteration.